# How to run locally Docker Container with cloud-run service account & GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gcloud, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run

I am trying to run locally a Docker Container of a Ktor app that connects to a Cloud SQL database.

This container is later to be pushed to Cloud Run, so I'm using an **IAM service account** in my environment variables for the authentication. I've been researching this problem for a week and haven't found an answer.

The steps I used are the following:

1. Create IAM service account "foo-cloudrun@foo-foo-121212.iam.gserviceaccount.com
2. Set the needed Roles for Cloud Run and Cloud SQL:

> ```
>    Cloud Build Service Agent
>    Cloud Run Admin
>    Cloud Run Service Agent
>    Cloud SQL Client
>    Cloud SQL Instance User
>    Viewer
> ```

3. Create a new key from the IAM account and save it to desktop.
4. Activate and login to the service account by running the following command on CMD:

> ```
>  gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file="C:\Users\user\Desktop\cloudrun-key.json"
> ```

5. Set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable to the key file location:

> ```
>   set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="C:\Users\user\Desktop\cloudrun-key.json"
> ```

6. Navigate to my application folder and [build the docker image](https://ktor.io/docs/docker.html#build-run):

> ```
>  docker build -t my-application .
> ```

7. [Start the image](https://ktor.io/docs/docker.html#build-run):

> ```
>  docker run -p 8080:8080 my-application
> ```

This is where I'm getting a vague exception: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException".

To find what's going on I tried to use [docker compose](https://ktor.io/docs/docker-compose.html) to see if I get a better idea. So I run the gradle **shadowJar** to create a .jar file in the build/libs directory, and then run **"docker-compose up"**.

This is where I'm getting this exception that baffles me, since I have set the environment variable to the proper location:

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials
> are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute
> Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_
> CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the
> credentials. See
> https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials
> for more information.

Dockerfile as instructed [here](https://ktor.io/docs/docker.html#prepare-docker):

```
FROM gradle:7-jdk11 AS build
# Copy local code to the container image.
COPY --chown=gradle:gradle . /home/gradle/src
WORKDIR /home/gradle/src
# Build a release artifact.
RUN gradle shadowJar --no-daemon 

FROM openjdk:11
EXPOSE 8080:8080
RUN mkdir /app
# Copy the jar to the production image from the builder stage.
COPY --from=build /home/gradle/src/build/libs/*.jar /app/my-application-docker.jar
# Run the web service on container startup.
ENTRYPOINT  [ "java", "-jar", "/app/my-application-docker.jar" ]
```

docker-compose.yml file:

```
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME: ${INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME}
      DB_IAM_USER: ${DB_IAM_USER}
      DB_USER: ${DB_USER}
      DB_NAME: ${DB_NAME}
      PORT: ${PORT}
      JDBC_DRIVER: ${JDBC_DRIVER}
      GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: ${GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS}
```

env. file:

```
JDBC_DRIVER=org.postgresql.Driver
DB_IAM_USER=foo-cloudrun@foo-foo-121212.iam
DB_NAME=my-database
INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME=foo-foo-121212:us-central1:database-sql-instance
PORT=8080
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=C:\Users\user\Desktop\cloudrun-key.json
```

DatabaseFactory.kt file like [this reference](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/HEAD/cloud-sql/postgres/servlet/src/main/java/com/example/cloudsql/ConnectorIamAuthnConnectionPoolFactory.java):

```
object DatabaseFactory {

    private val INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME = System.getenv("INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME");
    private val DB_IAM_USER = System.getenv("DB_IAM_USER")
    private val DB_NAME = System.getenv("DB_NAME")


    fun init() {
        Database.connect(hikari())

        transaction {
            SchemaUtils.create(FirstTable)
            SchemaUtils.create(SecondTable)
        }
    }


    private fun hikari(): HikariDataSource {

        val config = HikariConfig()

        // IAM AUTHENTICATION
        config.driverClassName = System.getenv("JDBC_DRIVER")
        config.jdbcUrl = String.format("jdbc:postgresql:///%s", DB_NAME)
        config.addDataSourceProperty("socketFactory", "com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory")
        config.addDataSourceProperty("cloudSqlInstance", INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME)
        config.addDataSourceProperty("enableIamAuth", "true")
        config.addDataSourceProperty("user", DB_IAM_USER)
        config.addDataSourceProperty("password", "password")
        config.addDataSourceProperty("sslmode", "disable")

        config.connectionTimeout = 10000 // 10s
        config.maximumPoolSize = 5
        config.minimumIdle = 3
        config.maxLifetime = 1800000; // 30 minutes
        config.isAutoCommit = false
        config.transactionIsolation = "TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ"
        config.validate()

        // Initialize the connection pool using the configuration object.
        return HikariDataSource(config);


    }

    suspend fun <T> dbQuery(block: () -> T): T =
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            transaction {
                addLogger(StdOutSqlLogger)
                block()
            }
        }

}
```

**Things that I have tried unsuccessfully:**

1. [Testing a Cloud Run service locally](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/testing/local#docker-with-google-cloud-access) . Getting NullPointerException

> docker run -p 8080:8080 -v
> ${GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS}:/tmp/keys/cloudrun-key.json:ro
> my-application-api
>
> docker run -p 8080:8080 -e GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/tmp/keys/cloudrun-key.json
> -v ${GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS}:/tmp/keys/cloudrun-key.json:ro my-application-api

2. Using my gmail user account to run the docker-compose up command by:

- Un-setting the environment variable (set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS= )
- gcloud auth login (to gmail account)
- gcloud auth application-default login (to set the default credentials to known location)
- running again the **docker run** command or **docker-compose up**

where I'm getting:

*" Error reading credential file from environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS, value 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\cloudrun-key.json': File does not exist."*

3. Setting the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in Windows system environment variables manually through system properties. Again same error.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: Never ever use service account key files (or in rare and exceptional cases). It's a major security issue. Here an article I wrote to solve your issue (with your own credentials): https://medium.com/google-cloud/use-google-cloud-user-credentials-when-testing-containers-locally-acb57cd4e4da

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow that's a lot of question :-)

**First** The following commands are mutually exclusive-ish:

This authenticates `gcloud` and its commands with the Service Account. When you run `gcloud something`, it will use the Service Account as its identity.

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account \
--key-file="C:\Users\user\Desktop\cloudrun-key.json"
```

This enables code built with Google's client libraries to use Application Default Credentials (ADC) to obtain the runtime identity for the code. It does **not** affect `gcloud`. It **does** provide an identity to your code.

> I assume `set` is a Windows environment variable command

```
set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="C:\Users\user\Desktop\cloudrun-key.json"
```

**Second** and I'll admit I scanned the question, you need to mount the service account into the container when it runs.

Using `docker` or `podman` etc.:

```bash
docker run \
--interactive --tty --rm
--publish=8080:8080 \
--volume=c:\Users\user\Desktop\cloudrun-key.json:/secrets/key.json \
--env=GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/secrets/key.json \
my-application
```

> The path `c:\Users\user\Desktop\cloudrun-key.json` is probably incorrect when using Docker. You may need to replace `\` with `/`. You may need to do something with the `c:`. I don't know how this gets mapped on Windows.

The `--volume` flag maps the location of the key on your **host** to (`:`) a location in the **container**.

In this case, in the container, the key will be `/secrets/key.json` and so this is the value to be used for `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`.

Using `docker-compose` it's going to be something like:

```
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
    - "c:\Users\user\Desktop\cloudrun-key.json:/secrets/key.json"
    environment:
      INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME: ${INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME}
      DB_IAM_USER: ${DB_IAM_USER}
      DB_USER: ${DB_USER}
      DB_NAME: ${DB_NAME}
      PORT: ${PORT}
      JDBC_DRIVER: ${JDBC_DRIVER}
      GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: /secrets/key.json
```

**Third** when you run the container on Cloud Run, it will leverage ADC and automatically use the identity of the Cloud Run service that you deploy. Cloud Run services have a default identity but you can specify an identity at deployment with [`gcloud run deploy ... --service-account=${SERVICE_ACCOUNT}`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/run/deploy#--service-account).

Thanks to ADC, you don't need to worry about mounting the key into the container or specifying an environment variable, it will just work.

Comment: you can't offer solution with service account key file. You provide lot of great answer, but service account key files must be banned for local, test or convenient usage! Have a look to that solution: https://medium.com/google-cloud/use-google-cloud-user-credentials-when-testing-containers-locally-acb57cd4e4da

Comment: @DazWilkin Thank you so much!!! I can't believe its working. I wasn't able to run it with the "docker run" command but with "docker-compose up" and the addition of "volumes:
      - "C:/Users/user/Desktop/cloudrun-key.json:/secrets/key.json" it works perfectly!

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I am aware of your article, but I think this doesn't work for service accounts, only user accounts -correct me if I'm wrong-. Also, If you are a solo developer and just test this locally, where is the danger in that?

Comment: @Theseus you are never solo! You code will live, other will use it, maybe your team will grow, maybe some freelance will join you. Or, you might do a mistake: commit the json file in a public github repo! (It's not a joke, I already did it when I started when Google Cloud). Best practices are here to prevent mistake, security breaches, improve scalability and collaboration. Using them from the beginning is the best that you can do for a safe and easy future! (It's not only related to security, but also to code comment, unit tests, branching in git,....)

Comment: svc account keys are not encocouraged but there are situations where they need to be used and have to be.   The're not that common have their place (so by banning its pretty much glossing over facts).     
  for official best practices here https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/best-practices-for-managing-service-account-keys

Comment: ADC doesn't work for me :( I'm trying to use Cloud Build to fetch a secret using nodejs secrets manager at build time. I have no clue what's going wrong, I'm following all the docs I can find

Comment: my problem was my build trigger was configured to use the inline cloudformation.yaml, not the repository cloudformation.yaml